# Moq the result that depends on input

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am a bit confused on Moq call. I need to Moq a function that takes an object. It should return a different object, whose content is generated by an existing function, that takes its input from field of the input object.

So I supply a complex object in input, and one of its fields is equal to some number, and I need to reply with object that is generated taking into account that some number.

I came up with the following sketch but it is full of errors. I appreciate a proper primer how to do what I need.

```
var processor = new Mock<IMyCommandProcessor>();
processor.Setup(d => d.ProcessCommand(It.IsAny<MyCommand>))
    .Returns((MyResponse r) => r.Results = new List{ newDto(aaa) });
```

newDto(aaa) is the call of a function, and instead of aaa I need a field that comes from MyCommand object given from input. How I can declare mocking here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: *'that takes its input from field of the input object'* which field? *'one of its fields is equal to some number'* which field? which number? What function you should call? Also it would be nice to understand what logic you are tyring to test - maybe you are using wrong approach here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `newDto(aaa)` is a call to a helper function then you could try:

```
processor.Setup(d => d.ProcessCommand(It.IsAny<MyCommand>))
         .Returns((MyCommand c) => new MyResponse(){ Results = new List<DtoType>(){ newDto(aaa)}});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just would add that new List<DtoType> would be the right syntax :) it was my mistake in question.

Answer (score 2):

Just a generic example :
you can replace `input + input` with any method of course.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMock()
    {
        var a = new Mock<IDictionary<string, string>>();
        a.Setup(d => d[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns((string input) => input + input);
        string result = a.Object["test"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use input parameters in Returns callback:

```
processor.Setup(d => d.ProcessCommand(It.IsAny<MyCommand>))
         .Returns((MyCommand c) => new MyResponse()});
```

However you cannot access the `newDto` function if it's defined on the class you are testing.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you are not using passed command

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, I'm not sure what OP wants to do here. I just added it so he can see the correct parameter type.